# How to change button background color when I click the button in React using Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, In my project I have two buttons, for First button I assigned a state for second button I written a function and I assigned a state as well. but my onClick function is not working. please help me to resolve this isssue.

This is App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "antd"
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [buttonOne, setButtonOne] = useState("red")

  const [buttonTwo, setButtonTwo] = useState("blue")

  const buttonTwoBackgroundColor = () => {
    setButtonTwo({
      backgroundColor: "red",
      border: "red"
    })
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Button style={{backgroundColor: buttonOne, border: buttonOne}} className="one" type="primary">First</Button>
      <Button style={{backgroundColor: buttonTwo, border: buttonTwo}} onClick={buttonTwoBackgroundColor} className="two" type="primary">Second</Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is App.css

```
.one {
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}



.two, .three, .four, .five {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set state to be an object when you have defined the defualt state as a string.

Update the default state to an object and then access properties like this:

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "antd";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
 

     const [buttonOne, setButtonOne] = useState("red");
    
      const [buttonTwo, setButtonTwo] = useState({backgroundColor: "blue", border: "blue"});
    
      const buttonTwoBackgroundColor = () => {
       setButtonTwo(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        border: 'red'
     }));
      };
      return (
        <div>
          <Button
            style={{ backgroundColor: buttonOne, border: buttonOne }}
            className="one"
            type="primary"
          >
            First
          </Button>
          <Button
            style={{ backgroundColor: buttonTwo.backgroundColor, border: buttonTwo.border }}
            onClick={buttonTwoBackgroundColor}
            className="two"
            type="primary"
          >
            Second
          </Button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function **buttonTwoBackgroundColor** you set **setButtonTwo** to a object. it should be a string.

```
  const buttonTwoBackgroundColor = () => {
    setButtonTwo("red")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

change 
`onClick={buttonTwoBackgroundColor}` 
to 
`onClick={setButtonTwo("red")}`

you are using useState as string at initialization and assigning an object in function below, which is not proper way!